# Vim autocmd to apply a user defined command to multiple specific (by filetype) tabpages?

Tags: vim, autocmd

I open my Vim session with multiple tabpages simultaneously.
Some of my tabpages are .txt files, some are not.

I have created, in my .vimrc, a command named Tran which refers to syntax.vim where are defined a few specific syntax highlightings for my .txt files.

```
:command Tran :source syntax.vim
```

My problems/questions :

1) When I open my Vim session, I would like to have all my .txt files highlighted thanks to the Tran command. I tried (in my .vimrc) :

```
:command Tran :source syntax.vim
autocmd filetype txt :Tran
```

… and failed.

2) For the time being, when I switch to a .txt tabpage, I immediately type the following command :

```
:Tran
```

and it works. But if I go to another tabpage, and later come back to my .txt tabpage (during the same session), all the highlighting has disappeared.

I suppose those 2 problems can be solved in 1 simple way. But which one ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of Vim makes filetype=text in .txt file.
And, you can use Syntax event for this purpose.
Try the following.

```
autocmd Syntax text :Tran
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion : it has no effect (neither good nor bad). Perhaps "something rotten" in my .vimrc ? Thanks, anyway.

Comment: filetype=text was added in recently.  
If your Vim is not support it, put a following file in ~/.vim/ftdetect/text.vim

    autocmd BufReadPost,BufNewFile *.txt setlocal filetype=text